# How to set currency in Windows Azure (XtraReport DevExpress)

Tags: silverlight, azure, devexpress, visual-studio-lightswitch, xtrareport

My application is on Lightswitch platform and culture set in general properties "en-US"
Application entity type set is "Money", currency code set is "INR", and Symbol Mode set is "Currency Symbol". 
After publishing to windows Azure, the currency displays in the screen is "Rupee Symbol " but in Xtrareport devexpress the cureency displays as "$" and as per my requirement it should be "Rupee Symbol".

Please help me to achieve so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked out for me this way,

```
<system.web><globalization culture="hi-IN" uiCulture="hi-IN" /></system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the UICulture of the current thread. My sense is that the Azure worker/site/etc uses en-us as its UICulture.

Comment: Hi @Seth, How do I set the UI culture, please guide me. I have place this code in web.config file but nothing worked out.                                        <system.web>
   <globalization uiCulture="en-IN" culture="en-IN" />
</system.web>

Comment: Awesome! Make sure to answer this as the right answer (if you don't mind).